# How to clean a certain field in a InlineFormSet?

Tags: django, inline-formset

I need to clean a specific field in an inline formset, and I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried with the formsets `def clean(self)` method but don't know where to save the cleaned value. If I try to set the cleaned value to `forms[0].data['field']` I get "This QueryDict instance is immutable" error.

In "normal" forms it works by using the `def clean_fieldXY(self)` method in which I `return cleaned_value`.

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the inline formset to use a form class, and then you can create a `clean` function for the field.

In `myapp/forms.py`:

```
class InlineFormsetForm(forms.Form)
    myfield = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=50)

    def clean_myfield(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['myfield']
        if data == 'badinput':
            raise forms.ValidationError("I hates it!")
        return data
```

Then, in `myapp/views.py`

```
from myapp.forms import InlineFormsetForm
from myapp.models import ParentRecord, ChildRecord

def editmything(request):
    MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentRecord, ChildRecord, form=InlineFormsetForm)
```